# Handling Unhandled Exceptions from Winforms components in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, exception

My application is built in WPF but it includes some WinForms components that we have written. When an exception is unhandled in one of the WinForms components it crashes the application.

I have implemented `DispatcherUnhandledException` for WPF events. This is good because it allows me to display an error and mark the exception as Handled to avoid the crash.

Can I do something similar with the non-WPF exceptions. I was hoping for the standard WinForms dialog that used to come up and allow the user to continue or quite the application?

**Edit**: WinForms exceptions do get caught in `DispatcherUnhandledException` but setting e.Handled to true doesn't stop the application from crashing.

Comment: can you show some code on how you are showing/using the Windows Forms forms ?

Comment: `DispatcherUnhandledException` should catch any unhandled exceptions in the UI thread. Do your WinForms components use other threads? Or are you accessing them from other threads by mistake?

Comment: @DavidePiras They are hosted in a WindowsFormsHost control in the WPF markup. E.g. windowsFormsHost.Child = [instance of WinForms control]

Comment: @svick Sorry, I should have made my question clearer. The WinForms exceptions were caught in DispatcherUnhandledException but setting e.Handled to true didn't stop the crash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried [System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) and [System.Windows.Forms.Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode.aspx) ?

Comment: How exactly have you used them? I've tried at the WPF App startup to set a handler for ThreadException and then I SetUnhandledExceptionMode to CatchException but the handler never gets called..

Comment: @Andrei have used it just like in the example in the linked msdn docs.

Comment: Did the same but the handler never gets called.. BTW, have a look at my related question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/12533008/1796