# Handle unhandled exception from c++ dll in WPF

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, dll

My WPF app uses external DLL's method (c++, nothing with UI, just logic) like this:

```
[DllImport("myExternDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern int externalMethod(string str);

int SomeWPFMethod()
{
   int res;

   try
   {
      res = externalMethod(str);
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
      LogError(e)
      return -1;
   }

   return res;
}
```

Note, that SomeWPFMethod called in separate from UI thread (if this matter).

When there is something wrong inside dll I've got

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
>   occurred

exception.

A have unhanded exception method set for app, but this does nothing:

```
Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += Current_DispatcherUnhandledException;

private void Current_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                e.Handled = false;
                return;
            }

            ShowUnhandledException(e);
        }
```

**Is there possible somehow to handle the exception to prevent application from crash?**

If extern method fails, I don't want to do anything, but app should still work. Now it's crashed.

Comment: maybe this will help [.NET interop and exception handling](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/liviuc/2009/10/13/net-interop-and-exception-handling-in-mixed-applications/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling Unhandled Exceptions from Winforms components in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111334/handling-unhandled-exceptions-from-winforms-components-in-wpf)

Comment: >>Thomas, 
Nope, this works for WinForms, not for WPF

Answer (score 1):

Since SomeWPFMethod is called in a thread separate from the UI thread,

> Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException

will not be able to catch this exception since it catches unhandled exceptions only from the main UI thread created by WPF.

Seems you need to use

> AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException

It catches unhandled exceptions generated from all threads running under the context of a specific application domain.

You can refer to the following articles that cover proper way to handle unhandled exceptions in WPF at great depth -

https://dzone.com/articles/order-chaos-handling-unhandled

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx

Hope this solves your problem.